# Python Multiprocessing Process Shared Array

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have python code that use `Process`:

```
def RunCode(jobs):
    jobs.remove(multiprocessing.current_process().name)
    print("Name: {}".format(multiprocessing.current_process().name))
    print("len: {}".format(len(jobs)))

def randomString(stringLength=10):
    """Generate a random string of fixed length """
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []

    while True:
        if len(jobs) < 5:
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=RunCode,args=(jobs,),name="process-camera-{}".format(randomString())) 
            jobs.append(p.name)
            p.start()
```

I want to share `jobs` array between the process, so there will not be more that 5 processes running. But it's seems like that when i remove the string inside `RunCode` function not effect on the main array.
Any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First calling the non-blocking function `p.start()` is not sufficient to guaranty calling `jobs.remove()` before next call.

Second, even if you ask for an explicit `p.join()` as a last line of code in the loop, `jobs` is probably deep-copied during fork on your OS, so the first iteration effectively removes the first entry, the second one gets a version of jobs with one entry, so it removes itself only from its own copy of `join` and show one entry and so on...

It is a bit clearer with this code:

```
import multiprocessing
import string
import random

def RunCode(jobs):
    print("Name: {}".format(multiprocessing.current_process().name))
    print("len: {}".format(len(jobs)))
    jobs.remove(multiprocessing.current_process().name)
    print("len: {}".format(len(jobs)))

def randomString(stringLength=10):
    """Generate a random string of fixed length """
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []

    while True:
        if len(jobs) < 5:
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=RunCode,args=(jobs,),name="process-camera-{}".format(randomString())) 
            jobs.append(p.name)
            p.start()
            p.join()
```

Ouput:

```
Name: process-camera-xdmlyloget
len: 1
len: 0
Name: process-camera-whwgmxbgrs
len: 2
len: 1
Name: process-camera-jbhzrsdtqg
len: 3
len: 2
Name: process-camera-oprinyvlkl
len: 4
len: 3
Name: process-camera-kyaafxiaoz
len: 5
len: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not share modifiable standard data-structures between processes. You must use either Queues/Pipes to communicate between processes, or the memory-mapping based data-structures described in https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Answer (score 0):

This isn't strictly an answer to the question, but I don't have the reputation to make a comment instead of an answer, so I have to put it here.

It looks like you're rebuilding a lot of the function of Python's [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module. You might be better off using that instead. It allows you to create a process pool with a maximum number of processes (5 in your case) and then pass jobs to the pool, which will either hand them to an available process or put them in a queue until a process is available.

You could likely achieve what you need with code that looks something like this:

```
from concurrent import futures

def do_thing(arg):
    """This is where you do the thing you want done in other processes."""
    return arg, arg ** arg

ex = futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)

done = []

for i in range(100):
    done.append(ex.submit(do_thing, i))

for thing in done:
    num, exp = thing.result()
    print(f'{num}**{num} = {exp}')
```